# How can I auto-format the style block in vue3 properly with TailwindCSS with colon character?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I have a vue file with a style block like this, using TailwindCSS and PostCSS

```
<style scoped lang="postcss">
.button {
  @apply bg-green-200 hover:bg-green-400;
}
</style>
```

In VSCode, with the Volar extension, I can perform auto-format. However, after auto-format, my style looks like this

```
<style scoped lang="postcss">
.button {
  @apply bg-green-200 hover: bg-green-400; # notice the space after hover:
}
</style>
```

This breaks TailwindCSS because it would treat "hover:" and "bg-green-400" as 2 separate classes.

What can I adjust to improve on this? I don't see a lot of option when trying to create ".vscode/settings.json" myself to control Volar.

I am using:

- Vue 3
- Nuxt 3
- TailwindCSS 3
- Volar VSCode extension
- VSCode

---

**Update**

I don't have any vscode setting in the root directory. Here is my VSCode global settings

```
{
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.rmd": "markdown"
    },
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook",
        "*.wasm": "default"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "**/.bloop": true,
        "**/.metals": true,
        "**/.ammonite": true
    },
    "workbench.productIconTheme": "fluent-icons",
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
    },
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "yaml": false,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": false,
        "scala": false,
        "properties": false,
        "rust": false,
        "python": false,
        "typescript": false,
        "http": false,
        "vue": false
    },
    "[java]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "scalameta.metals"
    },
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1500,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": [
        "gitpod.gitpod-remote-ssh"
    ],
    "remote.SSH.configFile": "/var/folders/rz/j1sp0c394pn5sv5pttp2pkt40000gn/T/gitpod_ssh_config-55598-oizqwPMdK6La",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font Mono",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 13,
    "editor.fontFamily": "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font Mono",
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[postcss]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe give a try to the Stylelint VScode extension.

Comment: How can I do this? Remember that this is in 1 single ".vue" file.

Comment: Stylelint doesn't really care if it's a Vue SFC or not. Install it and it should detect the CSS block itself. Works great on my side without any specific configuration AFAIK. Also, you may have some weird VScode configuration issue because I do not have such behavior. Mind posting your settings JSON file?

Comment: I just updated with my settings. I don't see anything weird with it atm.

Comment: This one is maybe not needed `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`.

Comment: I can't believe that I'm trying to find a solution for VSCode not breaking my CSS rules by default. Do you have a solution now one year later?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue as you. What I can do now is install the `postcss-nesting` package add it to the `postcss.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'tailwindcss/nesting': 'postcss-nesting',
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

In the style tag, you can do something like this:

```html
<style scoped lang="postcss">
.button {
  @apply bg-green-200;
  &:hover {
    @apply bg-green-400;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is totally different from what I want to happen. You are referring to a style item, such as `&:hover <and then some utilities>`, I am referring to the utilities themselves, i.e. the colon is within the utility classes `@apply hover:bg...`

Answer (score 0):

I found out using **prettier** for **.vue** files does the trick to a certain extend

settings.json

```
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
```

It will format the **template**, **script** and **style** block but leaves the CSS **@apply** rules **untouched**

Example:

**this will be formatted as expected**

```
             .base-button-focus                      {
  @apply focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:brand-primary;
}
```

**this will stay as it is**

```
.base-button-focus {
  @apply focus:outline-none         focus:ring-2            focus:ring-offset-2 focus:brand-primary;
}
```

**But at least it won't break the conditional modifiers like `hover`, `focus`, `md` etc away from the classes**